# MySpace OAuth2.0: Where are their endpoints in their documentation?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, myspace

I have a customer who wants to be able to login to his application using MySpace. I found a blog post stating OAuth2.0 is supported, however, I can't find any documentation for the authorize, token or even the restful endpoints for user data.

Does anyone know the following for myspace?

- What are the scope names?
- What is their authorization url?
- What is their token generation url?
- Does they have a restful API can for getting a unique
  userid?

Any help appreciated!